# More precise wildcard regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

I made a wildcard filter routine to match filenames with use of wildcards. For example: `*.js` gives me all js files in a directory.

However, when there is a `.json` file in the directory, I also get these. I understand why but that's not what I want.

I use this (picked up from a site) wildcardStringToRegexp function to build the RegExp (because I am not good at this):

```
function wildcardStringToRegexp( s ) 
{
    if( isValidString( s ))
     { return false; }

    function preg_quote(str, delimiter) 
    {
        // *     example 1: preg_quote("$40");
        // *     returns 1: '\$40'
        // *     example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
        // *     returns 2: '\*RRRING\* Hello\?'
        // *     example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
        // *     returns 3: '\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:'
        return (str + '').replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + (delimiter || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
    }


    return new RegExp(preg_quote(s).replace(/\\\*/g, '.*').replace(/\\\?/g, '.'), 'g');
}
```

---

```
function fnmatch( sMask, sMatch, bReturnMatches )
{
    if( !isValidString( sMatch ))
     { return false; }

    var aMatches = sMatch.match( wildcardStringToRegexp( sMask ) );

    if( bReturnMatches )
     { return isValidArray( aMatches )?aMatches:[]; }

    return isValidArray( aMatches )?aMatches.length:0;
}
```

---

for example:

```
fnmatch( '*.js', 'myfile.js' )   returns 1
fnmatch( '*.js', 'myfile.json' ) returns 1 , this is not what I want
```

How can I change the `wildcardStringToRegexp`() function , or what do I need to change that `fnmatch( '*.js', 'myfile.json' )` is not possible, is not valid so the fnmatch is more precise?

Comment: Does not work, get nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you are using might be overkill. You simply need to replace all occurrences of wildcards with a regex equivalent, and match the beginning and end of the input. This should work:

```js
const fnmatch = (glob, input) => {

  const matcher = glob
                  .replace(/\*/g, '.*')
                  .replace(/\?/g, '.'); // Replace wild cards with regular expression equivalents
  const r = new RegExp(`^${ matcher }$`); // Match beginning and end of input using ^ and $
  
  return r.test(input);
 }

console.log(fnmatch('*.js', 'myfile.js')); // true
console.log(fnmatch('*.js', 'myfile.json')); // false
console.log(fnmatch('?yfile.js', 'myfile.js')); //true
```

Comment: I wish comments could be shorter because I want to comment saying "nice work" but that's too short. So this is my longer comment to say "nice work" :)

Comment: Thanks, okay, nice however this doesn't work: fnmatch( '?yfile.*', 'myfile.js'); Is possible to add the '?' wildcard? The original function supports this.

Comment: That would be a matter of chaining another replace like `.replace(/\?/g, '.')`

Comment: That's pretty awesome, thanks for the amzing help. Much nicer now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated my answer to include the `?` wildcards

Comment: Start testing. Just one question tho, *.??? works (get all files with a 3 letter extension) however if there is a file, for example myfile.html it will be included as result. Is there an easy solution to this? This returns 1: fnmatch( '*.???', 'myfile.html' ); notice: stack removes the asterisk, makes text italic. [asterisk].???

Comment: Ah, that's because when `*.???` gets converted to regex, the `.` matches any character. That's partly what the `wildcardStringToRegexp` function is accounting for. 

The best solution is probably to go back to using that function but wrapping the result in regex anchors. 

Something like ```var aMatches = sMatch.match( `^${ wildcardStringToRegexp( sMask ) }$` );```

Comment: Good work sliptype. I needed the same functionality in Flutter/Dart and ChatGPT translated your function for us. Here it if someone needs it. 
<pre>
bool fnmatch(String glob, String input) {
  String matcher = glob.replaceAll('*', '.*').replaceAll('?', '.');
  RegExp r = RegExp("^$matcher\$");
  return r.hasMatch(input);
}
</pre>